# What does it mean if a JDBC driver is unable to find a particular class

Tags: jdbc, hive, birt, classnotfoundexception

I work with reports and currently seeing a warning in my BIRT designer(Eclipse) error logs:
"Cannot load driverClass: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"

I have dealt with classnotfound issues before and usually updating the correct driver resolved the issue, but this time the report is working and still, this warning is shown in error log and I am trying to understand why.
Looking at the below message it seems the oda driver is looking for 
"org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" class and unable to find it.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
>   cannot be found by
>   com.actuate.data.oda.jdbc.drivers_24.2.1.v201710020253

Please help me understand the warning message and how can I get rid of this.

Comment: Error is fairly self explanatory. Where have you put your Hive JDBC Driver jar? Where is that other library looking for it?

Comment: Thanks for responding,  The hive Drivers is placed inside the Plugin folder of the report designer installation and the other library is also inside the plugin folder. I am not sure where is that other library looking for it, how can I check that?